# Como por vários elementByID dentro de uma variavel só?

Tags: javascript

Eu queria saber se tem como e como que faço pra por vários elementDocumentID dentro de uma variável só.

Exemplo:

O código é pra fazer validação, o código esta assim:

```
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var nome=document.getElementById("nome").value;
var senha=document.getElementById("senha").value;
var rep_senha=document.getElementById("rep_senha").value;`
```

Comment: o que você está querendo fazer exatamente? Pegar os dados de um `<form>`?

Comment: Por que exatamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta usar um objeto JavaScript

```
dados = {
    email : document.getElementById("email").value,
    nome : document.getElementById("nome").value,
    senha : document.getElementById("senha").value,
    rep_senha : document.getElementById("rep_senha").value
}
```

E para acessar:

```
dados.email
```

Ou o campo que voce precisar

Answer (score 0):

Pode pegar todos os inputs usando o `document.querySelectorAll`, depois com o array de inputs pode usar a função `reduce` do array para transformar os inputs em um objeto `obj.name => value`, isso funciona genericamente para quantos inputs você tiver

```js
function data(){
 var form = document.querySelectorAll('input');
 var inputs = Array.from(form);
 return inputs.reduce((valorAnterior, valorAtual, indice, array) => {
  valorAnterior[valorAtual.name] = valorAtual.value;
  return valorAnterior;
 },{});
}

console.log(data());
```

```html
<input type="text" name="email" value="valueEmail"/>
<input type="text" name="nome" value="valueNome"/>
<input type="password" name="senha" value="valueSenha"/>
<input type="password" name="rep_senha" value="valueSenha"/>
```